# How should I deal with incorrect information given to me by a TA

Tags: teaching, teaching-assistant

I'm in an introductory CS class, and we have a small project we need to complete. I was struggling, so I went to the student(undergrad) TA's office hours, and asked a couple questions which made sense to me given my understanding of the material. He seemed preoccupied with work on his computer, but when I finished a question he would look up and say something like yes, that's correct, or "I see what your saying, that's a good question," and finally "Yes, if you use that data structure you get [Horrendous run time]." (I hypothesized this in my question) As a result, I rewrote my code trying to use different data structures, and I changed the fundamental algorithms I was using.

When my program still was not working today, I went to my professor's office hours, and ended up asking basically the same questions. It turned out that they were not, in fact, good questions, but were based on fundamental misunderstandings of the material, and in particular, the data structure I was talking about is exactly what is used and it gets a very good run time. (But my understanding of how to process the data was way off). Once my professor cleared this up, I rewrote my code and now it works.

In retrospect, I think the TA wasn't listening at all to my questions, and was just saying yes until I left. This had a serious negative impact on me, as I rewrote code that was on the right track and pored time into debugging, only to have to throw it all away.

So my question is: should I tell the professor about this, or just walk away? If it matters, the student will likely be TA again next semester.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you're making a big deal out of nothing.

Comment: @padawan How is that a reason to close? It seems like that would be an answer. Also, this question is not about "undergraduate admissions, life, and culture." It's about undergraduate education, a well established topic here.

Comment: Everyone make mistakes. In your case, TA made a mistake by answering you "yes" instead of "no." These things happen often. Your professor would've done the same mistake. If your reaction would have been to go to dean and report the professor, then you're really making big deal out of everything. If not, then why consider reporting TA to the professor. At the end, your program works.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, tell the professor about it. You shouldn't make a huge deal out of it, but send a brief, neutral e-mail saying that you were given wrong information in the office hours, that you got the impression the student was distracted and not really listening to what you said, and maybe ask how you can ensure that you do not waste time on red herrings next time.

If it's a one-off, and the student just had a bad day or a pressing deadline, it shouldn't have a big impact, but if other students also report similar problems the prof may watch the TA's performance a bit more closely, and may even decide to hire a different TA next year.

End-of-semester evaluations are also a good place to note this kind of experience. In my university the TAs even get their own evaluation form.

Comment: On the first reading, this advice sounded a little harsh in case of a one-off. But after thinking it through, I have to agree that this is the best course of action, also for the TA. He is still an undergrad, so relatively new to his job, and might want/need to learn how to properly do his job. And that also includes telling people "sorry, I have this important project right now that needs to be done tomorrow, just write me an email or come by in two days and I have time for you." instead of not listening. Note, however, that the TA might not see it that way if you tell on him.

Comment: I'd say I disagree based on the principle that it's best to first confront someone directly and give them a chance to correct their behavior before complaining to their supervisor.

Comment: I support the basic thrust of this answer, and I especially support the last paragraph.  Slight difference of approach: I'd attend the professor's office hours regularly, and mention on your way out one day that you've been choosing his office hours over the TA's office hours because ... and then mention briefly the experience you described here. // Basically, each semester, for each class, you should scope out the TA within the first month of the semester, to find out whether visiting his/her office hours would be a waste of time (or worse).